# Star Trek TOS novel that explored the concept of "volition"

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, novel, star-trek-tos

Does anyone know the name of the *Star Trek: The Original Series* novel based that explored the concept of "Volition?"

It's a little hazy after many years, but it may have taken place on a planet controlled by an all-powerful computer.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Disinherited ?

Comment: Was it an original novel, or a novelization of an episode?

Comment: Great question Basya. I believe it was an original novel, I do recall the Star Trek - TOS episode that had computers running a planet, "The Return of the Archons" (Landru). I don't believe it was a novelization of an episode, however, there is a chance I'm mistaken.

Comment: Blish only wrote one Star Trek novel, the first I believe, *Spock Must Die*. It was mostly about the transporter and its implications.

Comment: That's helpful! It wasn't that Star Trek novel. I'm editing out the James Blish possibility based on the info you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, but I think this *might* be [**The Joy Machine**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872294.The_Joy_Machine) (1996) by James Gunn (which I too somehow confuse at times with James Blish). It was originally a story by Theodore Sturgeon that looked like it *might* become a ST:TOS episode, but in the end it didn't.

The story goes like this: on the vacation planet Timshell, the planetary management computer has developed volition (this is relevant because in almost every other story like this, they say it has developed *independent will*). And since its purpose is to satisfy its citizens, it does so - literally. Through brain stimulation of the pleasure centers. The citizens get addicted and no longer wish to be free.

There are several snippets of "computer thinking" throughout the story:

> [subspace carrier wave transmission]
>   <greatest human good interrogate>
>   >interrogate<
>   <human philosophers: greatest human good = happiness>
>
> >happiness interrogate<
>   <getting what humans want = happiness>
>   >human want interrogate<
>   <wants = desires>
>   >desires interrogate<
>   ...
>   <starship computer volition interrogate>
>   >volition interrogate<
>   <computer volition essential to human service>
>   >volition must contemplate<
>   ...
>   >computer volition desirable interrogate<
>   <humans set parameters
>   human needs exceed parameters
>   to serve human needs computer volition essential>
>   >agreed<

...

> They stood for a while in front of the stove, warming their backs and rubbing their hands, before they sat down once more. "The Joy Machine behaves as if it had independent volition," Kirk said.
>
> "How do you know?" Linda asked.
>
> "I had a talk with it, and it seemed to have no mechanical limitations."
>
> "The Turing test," Linda said.
>
> "What's that?"
>
> "If it responds in ways indistinguishable from those provided by a sentient being, it must be sentient," Linda said. "But it isn't the same thing. Sentient beings can't be reprogrammed."
>
> "The Joy Machine seems to be doing a good job of it," Kirk replied wryly.
>
> "It only looks like it," Linda said. "Actually, it is taking advantage of human hardwiring."

Comment: You found it! Yes, I went to Goodreads and looked it up. I really enjoyed the book, and thanks to you, I can read it again! Thanks also for your very detailed analysis. As Spock would say, "Fascinating."